# How to display 4-5 lines of exception from Nested Exceptions via Regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex, exception, kibana

My requirement is to extract 4-5 (may vary as per the client requirement) lines each of the exceptions from all the nested exceptions and display the same on KIBANA via logstash.

I googled the same and found that Regex can be very handy for it. But I'm a newbie to Regex so don't know where to start.

Your help is much appreciated.

Note  : Unable to paste my exception stack trace and it is giving me an 'Spam related' exception.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are a lot of websites to try regex (such as https://regex101.com/ )

Comment: I tried various Regex like ((?<shortmessage>.*)) but it is giving me only 1st line of stack trace. I also tried regex as '(?PERROR\s-\s[^\n\r]+)' . But not a fruitful result.

Comment: Somehow I have written one Regex '(((?s).*Exception:\\s(.*))+)'  it still has some issues... Let say My Exception Trace have three exceptions but it is giving me 1st one twice followed by last. Skipping the 2nd exception. Total groupcount is 3 though.

Comment: Why via regex? It's easy enough to do with a simple loop, and very complex with a regex, especially if you have to vary the line count. You're using a hammer to crack a nut.

Comment: Hi EJP.. thanks for showing me the correct way.. this is what I have written and it is meeting with my expectations..

Comment: String[] exceptionTraceSplitted = aStackTrace.split("\n"); a for loop on it with below piece of code : if((StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(exceptionTraceSplitted[x], "Exception")|| StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(exceptionTraceSplitted[x], "Caused By")) && !isExceptionCounterEnabled) {exceptionCounter = 3;isExceptionCounterEnabled = true; }
if(exceptionCounter>0 && isExceptionCounterEnabled){         exceptionTraceBuilder.append(exceptionTraceSplitted[x].trim());exceptionCounter --;} 
if(exceptionCounter == 0 && isExceptionCounterEnabled){
            isExceptionCounterEnabled = false;  }